# How to send the POST request by http client 4.5.2

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm send a HTTP Post request using the http client like follow.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

the server is require some params inclue:method(String),appKey(String),signMethod(String),img(byte[])..

I use the follow code to send post, but response show that:"Missing required arguments:img".

```java
// append URL
String fullUrl = HttpRequestUtils.appendUrlRequestParams(API, params);

// builder request entity
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
for(Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
    multipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(PictureUploadConstant.img, imgs);
HttpEntity requestEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();

// post
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(fullUrl);
post.setEntity(requestEntity);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
try {
    // send post
    response = httpClient.execute(post);
    // response
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
    System.out.println("result" + result);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Anyone could tell me what 's wrong with it?

Comment: Is this c#? Java? Please add the language tag

Comment: It's Java. sorry, I am forget it.

Comment: Please post the complete error message you get and the line which produced the error message.

Comment: MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

for(Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) { 

 multipartEntityBuilder.addPart(entry.getKey(), new StringBody(entry.getValue(), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)); 
} 

multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("img", new ByteArrayBody(bytes, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, ""));